# How to prevent the ContentDialog from closing when home key is pressed in Windows phone 8.1..?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, messagedialog

```
private IAsyncOperation<ContentDialogResult> _Task = null;
private ContentDialog _message = null;            


        _message = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Content = "Hello",
            PrimaryButtonText = "EXIT",
            IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true,
        };

        _message.PrimaryButtonClick += message_PrimaryButtonClick;
        _Task = _message.ShowAsync();
```

Here I have created a Task for content Dialog, so that I can close the ContenDialog explicitly from code.

```
 How can I prevent dialog from closing when Home key is pressed and relaunched
```

Answer (score 12):

To prevent the dialog from closing handle its [Closing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.closing.aspx) event and set [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialogclosingeventargs.cancel.aspx) to true in its [ContentDialogClosingEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialogclosingeventargs.aspx) argument.

When initializing the dialog:

```
myContentDialog.Closing += ContentDialog_Closing;
```

Event handler:

```
void ContentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
{
    if (doNotClose)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```