# ContentDialog disappears when showing StatusBar

Tags: dialog, windows-phone-8.1

I've got a strange behavior when showing a `ContentDialog`. When the dialog is on screen and I drag the StatusBar down, the dialog disappears.

```
private ContentDialog _connectivityDialog = new ContentDialog { IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = false, IsSecondaryButtonEnabled = false, Title = "Test"};
```

Somewhere I just call `_connectivityDialog.ShowAsync();`

I made a simple project to reprduce this behavior:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0a6ad5xtrzii7sx/AADnbF9TGpfJnV9xnVG4FQMJa?dl=0

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution while investigating for another problem:

BackButton dismisses the dialog.

Solution:

```
_connectivityDialog.Closing += (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.Cancel = true;
            };
```

But be aware that the `Hide()`-Method is also affected. You can do a workaround like on this post:
[How to prevent the ContentDialog from closing when home key is pressed in Windows phone 8.1..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807209/how-to-prevent-the-contentdialog-from-closing-when-home-key-is-pressed-in-window)